# How to migrate an existing phonegap android project to windows8 or IOS

Tags: cordova, windows-8

I have created an application using phonegap on android. I was wondering how to migrate or reuse it completely for windows 8 and IOS. I have tried [Windows8 Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html). But it works only for very simple apps.

For a little complicated apps like mobile web apps what are the things we have to do ? 
In short has anyone used the same code base for windows8 and android in phonegap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the good thing about phonegap/cordova is that you don't really have to 'migrate' anything.

Using the CLI (Command Line Interface), you can simply add the platforms that you want your app to be built for. [see full doc here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface_add_platforms)

So in your situation, using your terminal/cmd line, change directory to your main app and you could use:

for windows phone 8

```
$ cordova platform add wp8
```

or windows 8

```
$ cordova platform add windows8
```

and ios

```
$ cordova platform add ios
```

and then by using

```
$ cordova build
```

cordova will build for all the platforms that you added so far. you can also build for only a specific platform, have a look at the documentation for more details.